# What is an analog meter (volt/ammeter) with the needle in the middle called?

Tags: terminology, voltmeter

I am making a demonstration which requires me to have access to a small extension that helps me prove `Faraday's Law of Induction` actually induces a current in a circuit. I want to get an analog volt or ammeter that has the needle in the middle allowing it to go both positive and negative to show that waving a magnet from side to side produces an AC current.

How is this type of meter called? I can only seem to find analog meters that go from zero to positive on amazon and the likes.

Comment: A centre-zero movement.

Comment: Maybe a galvanometer?

Comment: Galvanometer is indeed what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this type of meter called?

A "zero-centre" ammeter (or voltmeter) is probably what you are looking for: -

[image]

Taken from [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) wiki page

Comment: avometer > that :)

Comment: It's not an avometer like I've seen before

Comment: I know. I just like Avo's.  It's a generic moving coil meter. Still prefer these over digital for some things

Comment: Analog ones always have a cool vibe to them.